# How to replace the range value with address function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use the sparkline function but I want to use some formula to represent the range instead of using a reference like **J11:U11.**

Let's say I got two address formulas

> `=ADDRESS(ROW(E11),MATCH(E11,$A$10:$CU$10,0),4)`
> `=ADDRESS(ROW(F11),MATCH($F11,$A$10:$CU$10,0),4)`

which returns **J11** & **U11** respectively.

How could I get a result similar to `=sparkline(J11:U11)` with the formula above?

[example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16oeWF5ztZmN_iLXg2jI9oaW4d23PL3X5fNIMwakwDfI/edit#gid=0)

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample spreadsheet as a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just added the link, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

This seems to be a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If I understand correctly, there's a much easier way to accomplish what you wish than through the use of `=ADDRESS`.

For your example sheet, the formula below should produce the results you desire:

```
=SPARKLINE(FILTER($D5:5,$D$4:$4>=$B5,$D$4:$4<=$C5))
```

### Explanation

The `=FILTER` formula can be used to only return the results from a range dependent upon a specific set of criteria. In this case, the `=FILTER` only returns the columns from row 5 where the row 4 entry of that column is between the specified dates.

More specifically, the filter returns those columns from `$D5:5` where `$D$4:$4` is after `$B5` but before `$C5`. When this formula is placed in a cell and autofilled into the rows below it, Sheets automatically adjusts the relatively referenced portions of the formula for each new row you wish to calculate.

Functions used:

- [=FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [=SPARKLINE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289?hl=en)

Comment: Indeed, that's what I need. Thank you for the solution and the additional intro of XY Problem. Fruitful lesson today.